# Server Error in '/' Application on mvc jquery

Tags: javascript, c#, sql-server, ajax, model-view-controller

he partial view `Views/Shared/_RoomDetailsPartial.cshtml` was not found or no view engine supports the searched locations. The following locations were searched:
`~/Views/Room/Views/Shared/_RoomDetailsPartial.cshtml.aspx`

hey so I'm getting this error and I have no idea why.

here is my `js` code in index:

```
function LoadRoomDetail() {
    //divLoadRoomDetails
    $.ajax({
        async: true,
        data: 'GET',
        contentType: false,
        processData: false,
        url: '/Room/GetAllRooms',
        success: function (data) {
            $("#divLoadRoomDetails").html(data);
        },
        error: function () {
            alert('There is a problem! Fix it.');
        }
    });
}
```

here is my `RoomControler`

```
public PartialViewResult GetAllRooms()
{
    IEnumerable<RoomDetailsViewModel> listOfRoomDetailsViewModels =
        (from objRoom in objHMSdbEntities.Rooms
         join objBooking in objHMSdbEntities.BookingStatus on objRoom.BookingStatusId equals objBooking
         .BookingStatusId
         join objRoomType in objHMSdbEntities.RoomTypes on objRoom.RoomTypeId equals objRoomType.RoomTypeId
         select new RoomDetailsViewModel()
         {

             RoomNumber = objRoom.RoomNumber,
             RoomDescription = objRoom.RoomDescription,
             RoomCapacity = objRoom.RoomCapacity,
             RoomPrice = objRoom.RoomPrice,
             BookingStatus = objBooking.BookingStatus,
             RoomType = objRoomType.RoomTypeName,
             RoomId = objRoom.RoomId

         }).ToList();
    return PartialView("Views/Shared/_RoomDetailsPartial.cshtml", listOfRoomDetailsViewModels);
}
```

Comment: InvalidOperationException - and i also get this error from my windows log

Comment: return PartialView("_RoomDetailsPartial.cshtml", listOfRoomDetailsViewModels);

Comment: no need to specify the path to partial view

Comment: btw you can only use @{Html.RenderAction("yourPartialView");} and populate the model in controller and set the layout to null